# Pivot in aws athena

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table as follwos,

```
uname   date        value
fb      2019-09-13  10
uk      2019-09-13  20
fb      2019-09-14  30
us      2019-09-13  40
us      2019-09-14  50
```

Output should be as folows

```
unmae   2019-09-13  2019-09-14
fb      40          0
us      40          50
uk      20          0
```

```
 select queue_name,kv1('2019-06-03') AS A_v1 from 
(
 select queue_name,map_agg(wb,components_processed) as kv1
from hr_flash_fd_reviewer_policy group by 1
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *conditional aggregation*. Please note that this requires that you know in advance the possible values for the date column.

```
SELECT 
    uname,
    SUM(CASE WHEN mydate = date '2019-09-13' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS "2019-09-13",
    SUM(CASE WHEN mydate = date '2019-09-14' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS "2019-09-14"
GROUP BY uname
ORDER BY uname
```

NB: `date` is a really bad choice for a column name, since it clashes with a reserved keyword. I renamed it to `mydate` in the query.