# Pivot table in AWS Athena with many categories

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

There are few answers around how to pivot data using Athena-SQL. Their common drawback is that one has to know in advance what are all values of the column in the input data that will become the columns in the pivoted version.

For example, assume, the input data looks like:

```
User       Fact     Value
-------    ----     ------
102        1        a
101        1        b
102        2        c
103        3        d
...
```

and the expected pivot is:

```
User       Fact_1   Fact_2   Fact_3
-------    ------   ------   ------
101        b        NULL     NULL
102        a        c        NULL
103        NULL     NULL     d
...
```

Now the key challenge is that the number of unique values in `Fact` is high (say ~1k). How can I build the pivot table without manually specifying all the unique values of `Fact` (i.e. the columns in the result)?

For a limited number of columns, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931343/671013), I could do something like:

```sql
SELECT 
    User,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Fact = '1' THEN Value END) AS Fact_1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Fact = '2' THEN Value END) AS Fact_2
FROM my_yable
GROUP BY  User
```

It is also simple to create a table with the unique `Fact` values, but I don't know how to use it...